# How to find whether a tree node has children

Tags: tkinter, python-2.6

I am trying to find a code for knowing whether the tree node
has children in Tkinter python 2.6. I tried with similar wxpython code but it fails!
This is for I wanted to do some programming with my ttk treeview widget, if I can get these details
like if there is any child node exists(True/False) or how many child node count then it is easy for me 
to make "IF-Conditions" in my program.

Somebody please help me soon

Please note my code

```
childItems= self.tree.ItemHasChildren("Arithmetic")

print childItems
```

Error:

> AttributeError: Treeview instance has no attribute 'ItemHasChildren'

Comment: You can't assume that methods in Tkinter have the same name as corresponding methods in wxpython. Have a look at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Treeview). I don't know the module, but I think `get_children` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Dear Tobias, That is fine! get_children, I tried many times with that but having confused with its method argument(item=None), how to write and specify this parameter in get children method, some examples of this method will be good to understand, I couldnot find any so far, request you to help me please.

Comment: As I said, I do not have much experience with that module myself. I assume that you call that method on the root element of the tree, and pass the node you want the children of as an argument. Have you tried this?

Comment: As tobias_k said: have you try `print self.tree.get_children("Arithmetic")` ?

Comment: Dear @furas & @ Tobias,

Thank you very much for responding!

print self.tree.get_children("Arithmetic") OR NodesData = self.tree.get_children("Arithmetic")

Yes I tried the same and I stuck up with following error!!!
please note the error: line 60, in ResetTreedata print self.tree.get_children("Arithmetic") 
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\ttk.py", line 1231, in get_children
    return self.tk.call(self._w, "children", item or '') or ()
TclError: Item Arithmetic not found

Comment: Dear @furas & @ Tobias, Arithmetic is the primary parent root item in my tree widget and its has 10 other child nodes and its nested sub items.
I am not initially hurrying up to retrieve and see all those tree items into a string but at least one if I can see that will be
great to go after the rest so I thought the tree very first root item(Arithmetic) will give me sure result but disappointing! 
then how can I use this method randomly to  find any sub item and its childs? help me please soon

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same, and came up with this:

```
if tree.get_children([iid_of_the_active_selection]):
  pass
```

It works for single selection configuration (selectmode="browse").
Not sure if this is what you were looking for, but hope it helps.